# XCode table view rotating from Portrait to landscape hiding the first row

Tags: ios, ipad, tableview, landscape, portrait

In my app i have a table view. Lets say for example i have 10 rows worth data in the table view with a navigation bar at the top.I launch the app in portrait mode. I see 10 rows.

Now i rotate the iPad to landscape mode. I see only 9 rows. 1 row is hidden beneath the navigation toolbar at the top.

I rotate it back to portrait and still i can see 9 rows only. 1 row is still hidden beneath the navigation bar. I drag the table view and see the 1st row. So my question is what changes do i make to see all 10 rows even when i change from portrait to landscape and vice-versa. I tried to change the setFrame values for tableview but no luck. If you need more info, please ask.Thanks.

Comment: try to edit your question, it is hard to follow.

Comment: is navigation bar comes from navigation controller stack or you just dragged a navigation bar to the view?

Comment: @SpaceDust. It came from navigation controller stack. I DID NOT drag and drop it to view.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have a complete answer for you, I have no idea why your first row goes under beneath the navigation bar, maybe you should provide additional code or screen shots for that.

In worst case I would do either make the tableview grouped and arrange the `-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` 
or I would drag and drop a dummy view from objects in interface builder to above the tableview , that way first row couldn't go under the navigation bar.

Anyways, If you have to show the all rows both in portrait and landscape you can detect the orientation changes and make your row height smaller or larger.

Add a notifier in the viewWillAppear function

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)  name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification  object:nil];}
```

The orientation change notifies this function

```
- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification{
  [self.tableview reloadData];
}
```

change row height depending on the orientation and shrink the rows when the orientation changes

```
//row height
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) 
{ 
    //portrait mode view 
    return 40.0; //play with the value according to your needs   
}
else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) 
{
    //landscape view 
    return 30.0; //play with the value according to your needs
}

}
```

Comment: It sort of works with this: UIEdgeInsets inset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(44, 0 ,0, 0); 
 self.tableView.contentInset = inset; My top row does not hide any more. But sometimes i am getting an empty row at the top. But if I move between landscape and portrait it disappears and i can see all the 10 rows.

Comment: I dont know why its happening it shouldn't, well good luck on your quest :)